# Using Server Sent Events in NodeJS not recieving data on client-side

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, server-sent-events

I have one webpage with text input for one webpage and I want to obtain the information.

In the client I have this:

```
function login() {
    webpage = document.getElementById("webpage").value;
    alert(webpage);

    source = new EventSource(
        "http://localhost:8000/register?name="+webpage, 
        {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' :'*'}
    );

    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        var a = event.data;
        alert(a);
    };
}
```

In the server I have this:

```
response.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type' : 'text/event-stream; charset=utf-8',
    'Cache-Control' : 'no-cache',
    'Connection' : 'keep-alive',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
});
```

But, I'm trying to obtain the `a` and the `alert(a)` doesn't do nothing. Any idea what's the problem in this code? Or how to make it work? Suggestions in jQuery are also welcome.

Comment: You haven't written/sent any data from the server, you've only just set the headers. You're using [Server Sent Events with NodeJS](http://google.com/search?q=server+sent+events+node.js) so search around how to use it. [Here's a good start](http://www.futureinsights.com/home/real-time-the-easy-way-with-eventsource-angularjs-and-nodejs.html). Basically you also need to actually *send* the events/data, something like `res.write('event:data\n')`

Comment: @laggingreflex That looks like an answer, not a comment :-).  (And, assuming that is the complete node.js script, it will be the right one!)

Comment: @DarrenCook thanks for the heads up. I was also confused whether OP's snippet is incomplete script and what I suggested might indeed be the answer. Turning it into answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you haven't actually sent any data from the server, just setting the headers doesn't do much.

You also need to actually send the events/data

```
res.write('event:data\n')
```

You're using [Server Sent Events with NodeJS](http://google.com/search?q=server+sent+events+node.js) (something you may have been unaware of at the time of asking) so search around how to use it. [Here's a good start](http://www.futureinsights.com/home/real-time-the-easy-way-with-eventsource-angularjs-and-nodejs.html).